# C++ parsing ambiguity: Constructor vs. parenthesized declarator

Tags: c++, parsing, yacc

I'm trying to write a yacc (menhir) grammar for parsing a very reduced subset of C++ (no templates, headers only with no function bodies allowed...) and am already running into ambiguities.

```cpp
typedef int B;

class A {
   A();     // (*)
   B(c)();  // (**)
};
```

Case * is a constructor and case ** is a parenthesized declarator. How does the parser tell the difference? I can imagine some ways I *could* tell, but I want to know how a compliant c++ parser does it. I also understand that I likely won’t be able to parse even a practical subset of C++ with yacc, but I just want to understand a bit better what’s going on. In the end maybe I’ll switch to a parser combinator or something. Also, I should note that I have zero interest in linking against clang as I intend to add some custom syntax.

Comment: Oh sorry! I goofed — I’ve removed the typedef. The B typedef is to ensure that the lexer doesn’t see it as a keyword. I intended to make a contrived definition of ``int c();`` but with a parenthesized declarator.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfIr7lKT4Sk

Comment: @user17732522 this is really helpful. It looks like even the most basic of c++ code needs lookahead AND type information.

Comment: Related: [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: I guess I wonder how much of the ambiguity you can rip out while still parsing most very vanilla, even ascetic code. Seems like not much!!!

Comment: Can you explain why you see an ambiguity here? B() is a declaration without a declaration specifier sequence, but starting directly with a declarator-id. B(c)() is not. B is part id the declaration specifier seq specifying the return type. The spec specifies rules that dictate what parts of a declaration belong to the decl specifier seq and what not anymore

Comment: There is no "constructor" non-terminal in any of the ISO C++XX specs. What grammar are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing C++ is frustrating exercise, because C++ is essentially not context-free. You need to know whether an identifier refers to a template, a type, or something else, and name resolution in C++ is not a simple task either. You might, for example, have to instantiate a template in order to know whether a member of templated class is a variable or a typename. (Programs only have to use `typename` for names in dependent types.)

So you certainly cannot expect to parse a translation unit without considering included header files. (Anyway, you couldn't do that because a header file could define a macro whose expansion changes the syntax in unexpected ways. So you need a preprocessor.)

*When I wrote this answer, my eyes had skipped over the parentheses in which OP noted that by "yacc" they meant "menhir". Sorry. Unfortunately, menhir does not generate GLR parsers, as far as I know. But I think the approach is still valid, and useful enough that I'm leaving it in place. Perhaps there is an OCaml GLR (or GLL) parser generator, or perhaps C/C++ generated code is still of use.*

Having said all that, all is not lost. You could use bison to generate a GLR parser, and then try to write custom disambiguation functions. If the disambiguation function needs to know whether a name is a typedef or not, it can try to look it up in the symbol table. Unlike the classic "lexer hack" approach, GLR disambiguation happens in the parser, so it doesn't require building unwieldy backchannels.

This can be an iterative process, because you don't need to figure out how to resolve ambiguities which are not present in the particular code you are trying to compile. Eventually, you'll probably want to handle all of them, but doing them as needed might prove to be a more fulfilling experience.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, recognizing constructors (and destructors) in C++ requires recognizing the name of the containing class specially, distinct from any other identifier.

This can be done with a contextual lookup in the lexer returning distinct tokens.  Inside the `{`...`}` composing the class A body, the lexer could recognize the `A` token and return a different token type for it (distinct from the TYPENAME token it would return for `B`)

Comment: This is helpful! Is this what clang, gcc, and MSVC do? I mean— they’re hand written recursive descent but do they keep a running index of types? This raises the question of whether you can parse a header file without the definitions mentioned in #included headers! I guess not!

Comment: I recommend looking at what should happen at the C++ Standard first, before digging up implementations.

Comment: The spec says you should lookup the identifier "A" and if it refers to the injected class name, it will declare a constructor (if I'm not mistaken). Apparently class member names are not allowed to be the name of their class, therefore an as-if optimization that just lexically compares "A" with surrounding class name maybe is possible.